# Needs a div element to take 100% of width of sweet alert 2 box

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert2

I have  two divs that are displayed in a sweet alert 2 box. The problem i'm having, is that the divs do not take the full width of the sweet alert box 2, as if there was some padding or margin that i can't overwrite. I've tried to set the full width of the widths to 100%/max-content, but it seems that it isn't working.
Here is my code:

```
  MySwal.fire({
      showConfirmButton: false,
      customClass: "custom-position-swal-edit-history",
      html: ` <div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mt-2 rename-delete-popup renameActionClass">
          <img  alt="" src="/images/rename discussion.svg"></img>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div >
      <div class="row">
      
        <div class="col-12 mt-2 rename-delete-popup deleteActionClass">
          <img alt="" src="/images/delete discussion.svg"></img>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     `,
 };
```